# I want to update a boolean field in a different model using a foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have a unit model and a tenant model.
`

```
class Unit(models.Model):
   property_name = models.ForeignKey('Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   floor = models.IntegerField()
   unit_type = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   rent_value = models.IntegerField()
   occupied = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def __str__(self):
      return '%s' % (self.unit_name)

class Tenant(models.Model):

   property_occupied = models.ForeignKey('Property', blank=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   unit_occupied = models.OneToOneField('Unit', unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tenant')
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   id_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
   phone_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
   date_occupied = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return '%s, %s, %s' %  (self.unit_occupied, self.first_name, self.last_name)`
```

I want to update the unit.occupied field to true whenever I add a tenant and false whenever I delete a tenant.I want to do it automatically. I'm using a onetoone field on the tenant model to assign a unit to a tenant because a unit can only have one tenant

I am using a tenant_form to add tenants and a unit_form to add a unit. How can I update the specific unit_occupied field for the tenant i'm adding automatically when i add/delete a tenant?

This is my views.py:
`

```
def add_tenant(request):
form = AddTenantForm

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddTenantForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)

        messages.success(request, 'Tenant added successfully')
    
    # units = Tenant._meta.get_field('unit_occupied').remote_field.model
    # for unit in units:
    #     ou = unit
    #     if ou.occupied is False:
    #         ou.occupied == True
    #         ou.occupied.save(commit=True)
    
    return redirect('tenants')

    # else:
    #     messages.error(request, 'Unit is already occupied')


else:
    form = AddTenantForm

context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'property/add_tenant.html', context)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
I grabbed the unit from the tenant submission form and used the id to update the specific unit in the Unit model

```
def add_tenant(request):
  form = AddTenantForm

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddTenantForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        unit_occupied = form.cleaned_data.get('unit_occupied')
        print(unit_occupied)

        form.save(commit=True)

        ou = Unit.objects.get(id=unit_occupied.id)
        if ou.occupied is False:
            ou.occupied = True
            ou.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Tenant added successfully')
        
        return redirect('tenants')

    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Unit is already occupied')
```